# ownership & permissions inside /var for systemd service

Tags: permissions, systemd, security, non-root-user, root-filesystem

I'm working on an application that needs to read some config files under `/etc` and write to a db file under `/var/lib`

I'm working on a `.service` file in order to enable this application to be executed as a systemd service.

This application does a lot of networking related tasks, with peers that could sometimes be unknown.

I set the User parameter of the `.service` file to a regular user (not root), because I want to be cautious about the security implications related to networking and unknown peers. But that is preventing the application from writing to the db, because it doesn't have write permissions for `/var/lib`.

What is the secure approach to this setup?

Comment: Can you change ownership of the DB files under `/var/lib` to match the `User` you're using for the systemd service?

Answer (score 0):

My solution was similar to @filbranden suggestion in the comments (thanks!).

The admin user belongs to a specific group. I set group ownership of `/var/lib/db` to this group (user ownership is still `root`), and set this directory's permissions to `775` (`drwxrwxr-x`, group has `w` permissions).

Now, because the systemd service is executed by the admin user, writing to `/var/lib/db` happens without errors.